# react-app-rewired add writeDisk option on devserver

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, webpack-dev-server, react-app-rewired

I am using react-app-rewired to override my webpack configurations. But I tried to set writeDisk option but it doesn't work. Here is config-overrides.js file

```js
const {
  override,
  disableChunk,
  addWebpackResolve, addWebpackAlias
} = require('customize-cra');

module.exports = {
  webpack: override(
      // some overrides here
  ),

  devServer: (configFunction) => {
    return (proxy, allowedHost) => {
      const config = configFunction(proxy, allowedHost);
      config.writeToDisk = true;
      return config;
    };
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

try
`config.devMiddleware.writeToDisk = true;`

Comment: This is the way. Link: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverdevmiddleware